# Make 2 volumes in docker gcc and java

Tags: gcc, docker

I have a docker volume set up in a `gcc` container. I need to compile the code and give it some `stdin` through a text file. I'm able to do that using the following command.

```
docker run \
  -v /home/usr/workspace/proj/WebContent/files:/mycode \
  gcc:4.9 \
  sh -c 'cd mycode; gcc -o myapp ./mycode.c; ./myapp < ./test.txt'
```

now my question is, I need to make a separate folder for each of my users with their username, but the text.txt stays in the same folder as above. How do I give them their own paths. because right now i get an error that test.txt is not found, and of course it wouldn't. I tried making a separate volume for the test.txt but I guess making two volumes in one container isn't possible or I'm doing it wrong.

What I've tried (please don't judge, i'm just learning :P)

```
docker run \
  -v /home/usr/workspace/proj/WebContent/file/username:/mycode \
  -v /home/usr/workspace/proj/WebContent/file/:/tst  \
  gcc:4.9 \
  sh -c 'cd mycode; gcc -o myapp ./mycode.c; cd tst; ./myapp < ./test.txt'
```

Comment: Do you just need to do "cd ../tst" instead of "cd tst"?

Comment: @AdrianMouat no that didn't work out :(

Comment: It's easiest to debug if you run with -it and open a bash shell (/bin/bash). You should be able to figure out where it goes wrong then.

Comment: Okay, but this is the right method, right?

Comment: BTW, when I was suggesting a reproducer other folks could run, not requiring directories other people won't have (like `/home/usr/workspace/proj/WebContent/file/username`) is part of that. A fully self-contained reproducer would download extra content it needed from git, or create dummy files, or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a close look at this command:

```
sh -c 'cd mycode; gcc -o myapp ./mycode.c; cd tst; ./myapp < ./test.txt'
```

Because you first `cd mycode` and then `cd tst` inside the same shell, you're trying to `cd mycode/tst`, whereas your mount is at `/tst`.

Similarly, `myapp` is in `/mycode`, not in `tst`, so you can't run `./myapp` inside the `tst` directory and expect it to work.

Instead:

```
sh -xc 'cd /mycode && gcc -o myapp ./mycode.c && cd /tst && /mycode/myapp < ./test.txt'
```

Comment: Output: + cd /mycode
+ gcc -o myapp ./mycode.c
+ cd /tst
+ /mycode/myapp
0+0
The 0+0 is the already compiled exe file.

Comment: That looks like what I'd expect from successful execution. Why are you telling me this? Do you have reason to believe there's a bug in play?

Comment: The fact that those commands ran successfully mean that `/tst` is mounted, just as `/mycode` is, ie. the log you just pasted is evidence that this answer works just as it should.